# How can I tell if a redirect is still externally linked?

Tags: google-search-console, url, backlinks

I renamed some of my pages (for consistency), and put this into my .htaccess file:

```
Redirect permanent   /old/name   https://mysite/new/name
```

It's been a while now, and I'd like to delete that redirection, but first I need to know if anyone still has any pages with the old URL.

Google Search Console will show me links to the new name, but I don't see any way to look for the old name.

Is there an easy way of doing this?  (Not necessarily using GS Console.)

Comment: Even if there are not links to your old pages any more, Googlebot will still come back and visit them indefinitely.  It is better for SEO to keep your redirects in place forever.

Comment: I take the opposite view. Sometimes it is just better to pull the bandage off quickly and be done with it. If the page is gone, it is gone. Redirect where it still makes sense, however, there is no sense in carrying old dead weight. As for finding links to old pages, other than SEO link sites like SEMRush and Alexa and others, there is nothing out there. Sorry. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Your server's access logs should contain all requests to `/old/name` that triggered 301 redirects (the response). You might have separate logs for HTTP and HTTPS traffic.